# How to live stream on facebook via ffmpeg?

Tags: facebook, ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04, rtmp, live-streaming

I am trying live streaming on facebook via ffmpeg but I get one error. As the error, I must use AAC instead of mp3. But I don't know how to do it.

Error: `Bad audio codec 2 (MP3). Accepted audio codecs: AAC`

Normally, I can run command below for youtube succesfully.

`ffmpeg -i "rtmp://..." -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 
-pix_fmt yuv420p -preset medium -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2500k 
-acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 6 -qscale 3 -b:a 
712000 -bufsize 512k -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/key"`

But when I run command below with facebook rtmp, error gets.

`ffmpeg -i "rtmp://..." -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 
-pix_fmt yuv420p -preset medium -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2500k 
-acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 6 -qscale 3 -b:a 
712000 -bufsize 512k -f flv "rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/key"`

I am user of Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace `libmp3lame` with `aac` and for `-b:a` you probably want a value of `128k`.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: ffmpeg -re -i .rtmp://... -acodec libmp3lame  -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -s 426x240 -bufsize 6000k -vb 400k -maxrate 1500k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 30 -r 30 -f flv "rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/111111111111111?ds=1&a=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

Answer (score 2):

In your ffmpeg command, you have this:

```
-acodec libmp3lame
```

This is encoding the audio stream into MP3. You'll need to change that. You might need to use something like this:

```
-acodec libfdk_aac
```

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC

To reference Facebook's "Live Video Specs" from  https://www.facebook.com/facebookmedia/get-started/live:

> The Live API accepts H264 encoded video and **AAC encoded audio only**.

Comment: Most users don't have access to `libfdk_aac` (license makes distribution problematic so ffmpeg must be compiled) so `aac` can be used instead.

Comment: how do i install this on ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, to add acc add '-strict -2'

So replace `libmp3lame` with  `aac -strict -2`